# Weird address for string literals

Tags: c++, g++, x86-64, osdev

I'm doing my own operating system project, [PS64](https://github.com/0x00000FF/philosophers-stone), and I managed to boot 64bit kernel.

I made console output for it, and it seems worked. however, wrong text printed out.

GDB says, passed pointer was `0x28`, so far away from the address which the pointer should have.

```
// KernelStart.cpp
void KernelStart() {
    KernelConsolePrint("Hello!");
}

// Console.hpp
void KernelConsolePrint(const char* str, const BYTE attribute = 0x07) {
    // str points far wrong address at this function
}
```

What's the reason for it? **64bit kernel is copied to `0x200000` from back of 32bit kernel image and starts at `0x200000`**, of course I passed linker parameter for text session on there.

I tried with it `char` array, it also points wrong address but much nearer address that 1~4 bytes front of normal address.

```
// KernelStart.cpp
void KernelStart() {
    const char[] str = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', '\0' };
    KernelConsolePrint(str);
}

// Console.hpp
void KernelConsolePrint(const char* str, const BYTE attribute = 0x07) {
    // ...
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { // changed loop cond because str points NULL character
        *( ( WORD * ) graphic ) = _CONSOLE_CHAR(str[i], attribute);
    }
}

// output
[  ]Hello!
 ^ two characters are appended
```

Comment: Why are you passing wrong number of arguments into `KernelConsolePrint`?

Comment: @VTT because its parameter `attribute` is a default parameter. I missed to describe it. sorry.

Comment: @anatolyg Ok. I revised this post with your advise.

Comment: My best guess. You aren't actually in 64-bit long mode and your 64-bit code is being executed as 32-bit code.

Comment: Looking at your GDT and related code you seem to be using a CS of 0x18. If I'm not mistaken you have defined that as a 32-bit Code Segment and not a 64-bit one. Selector 0x08 seems to be the 64-bit one but I don't see where you do a long jump to it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh gosh! I have revised `jmp 0x200000` to `jmp 0x08:200000`, and it works! Thank you very much! XD

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of the other.Although the questions appear quite different they boil down to running 64-bit code in 32-bit mode and the side effect appears to be video output not working as expected. My answer for that question discusses this issue.

Comment: Good. I have learned a lot. Thank you again.